# Unable to increment counter using SharedPreferences in Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, counter

I am just a fresher in Android and I have a scenario where the user can take a photo using camera and the photo would be stored in SDCard. I need to save the photos with a dynamic name i.e, I want the image name as Image 1,Image 2 and so on. I set the counter value as 1 initially so the first image would be stored as Image 1 and next time the counter would increase the value and store again.

**Issue :**

My problem here is that I am not able to increase the counter value every time I close and re-open the app. I have tried a lot and it sets the counter back to 1 again.

**CODE :**

```
int count;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        int defaultValue = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("count_key",count);
        defaultValue = count;
        editor.putInt("count_value",defaultValue).commit();
        if(count == 1)
        {
            count = 1;
            getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putInt("count_key",count).commit();

        }
        else
        {
             ++count;
            getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putInt("count_key",count).commit();
            count = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("count_key",count);
            System.out.println("The count value is " + count);
        }
```

On executing, it returns the count value as 1 every time and does not seem to increment the count value. It should be 1 the first time i open it and then 2 and so on. Is there a problem in my logic or am going wrong with SharedPrefs. I have surfed a lot on StackOverFlow but did not seem to come across with the style that I need. Any help would be highly appreciated guys. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
++count;
```

put this before if loop , not inside the else loop. or use the following code for increasing the count

```
int count = 0;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        int defaultValue = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("count_key",count);
             ++defaultValue;
            getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putInt("count_key",defaultValue).commit();
            count = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("count_key",count);
            System.out.println("The count value is " + count);
```

Comment: THE most simplest answer and accurate at the same time. Thanks you so much pal.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you have increment your ***count*** variable in the scope of for loop. So its create a problem.

So put

```
++count;
```

out side the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
int count;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        int defaultValue = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("count_key",count);
        count = defaultValue+1;  // change this line
        editor.putInt("count_value",defaultValue).commit();
        if(count == 1)
        {
            count = 1;
            getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putInt("count_key",count).commit();

        }
        else
        {

            getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putInt("count_key",count).commit();
            count = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("count_key",count);
            System.out.println("The count value is " + count);
        }
```

you try to put your value that get from share Preference into count but you use `defaultValue = count;` you must change that with `count = defaultValue;`

Answer (score 1):

```
int count;
```

now count value is 0,
after that ++count its value becomes 1. now below code will keep its value always 1.

```
if(count == 1)
    {
        count = 1;
        getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putInt("count_key",count).commit();

    }
```

hope ur clear

Comment: Thanks man. I too had my doubts at those points, you just made it clear.